# Download PDF file when button triggers jquery

Tags: jquery

I created a page in which I have a preview of a pdf file and a download button and I wanted to download the file after I trigger the button. I found some answers and I tried to apply them on my page.

my html button:

```
<div class="FilePreview"></div>
<button type="button" id="Download" class="btn btn-secondary">
   <i class="fas fa-download"></i> Download File
</button>
```

button trigger function

```
$("#Download").on("click", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var link = document.createElement("a");
      link.href = pdf_link;
      link.download = `${Name_}.pdf`;
      link.target = '_blank'
      link.click();
      link.remove();
});
```

but the result was it only opens the pdf file on a new browser window and it didn't download the file which doesn't meet my requirement which is to automatically download the pdf file when I clicked the button.
then I found that I need to add `Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=downloaded.pdf` on my response header.

After I added `Content-Disposition` on my response header what happen instead was it automatically downloaded the file even if I haven't clicked the button.  It downloads the file after the request.

what I wanted is to download the file only after I clicked the button without opening new tab window

Comment: use this: https://www.convertplug.com/plus/docs/download-pdf-file-forcefully-instead-opening-browser-using-js/

Comment: will it still work if i removed `Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=downloaded.pdf` on my response header?..